# I am creating an app for google glass and I have the game_menu.xml file why do I keep getting an error for making a menu?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, google-glass

This is my code:

```
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.xml.game_menu, menu);
```

Its giving me an error for xml.game_menu

I've included a screen shot.

Comment: Should be `R.menu.game_menu`

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't work menu ends up highlighting as red along with MenuInflate and WindowUtils.

Comment: So either your file is invalid, or not on the correct folder.

Comment: rename file to game_menu.xml (make sure it's in res/menu folder) and use R.menu.game_menu in code